# pandas row arithmetic based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how I can do a conditional difference between rows in Pandas.  For example in the table below, if I start with only the title and number columns, I want to create a diff column that takes difference in the number column between the current row and the prior row, but only if the title in the current row is the same as the prior row.  If not I want to leave it blank, or fill it with a null, etc.

I know how to create the diff column by doing

```
df.['title']=df.['number'].diff(1)
```

but this will leave me with meaningless diffs between different titles

this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
| title | number | diff |
|-------|--------|------|
| a     | 4      | NaN  |
| a     | 10     | 6    |
| a     | 13     | 3    |
| b     | 5      | NaN  |
| b     | 7      | 2    |
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `groupby`:

```
df.assign(diff=df.groupby('title')['number'].diff())
```

Output:

```
     title  number  diff
0   a            4   NaN
1   a           10   6.0
2   a           13   3.0
3   b            5   NaN
4   b            7   2.0
```

Comment: you can add lambda x :x-x.shift() :)

Comment: You are too fast:)

Comment: @Wen, .diff() works perfectly here so why use lambda?

Comment: @Vaishali Yes, you are right , I will recommend the flexible method, assuming , `diff()`=`x-x.shift()`, but with`lambda` you can also , do `x-x.shift(2)`

Comment: I was trying something like this but it just seems to hang when working with a  non trivial sized data set...say 20,000 rows.  Any idea why that would be?

Comment: @wildpygmy It should run pretty fast.20K rows is not alot of rows.

Comment: @ScottBoston it's actually 200K rows (my typo) but it just hangs. And even if I could get this to complete, I'm not sure this would actually work for what I'm trying to do.  The example table above is simplified.  My actual data is grouped by several columns and then put into chronological order based on time stamps, so the order of the current dataframe is important.  Think of it as ordered by State, then City, and within each City there are timestamps.  I want to keep the sorting by groups/chronological order and only take the difference in number if the city is same as the row above.

Answer (score 3):

If your `title` column is already grouped. If it isn't the sort first. Sort will be stable and preserve row order.

```
df.assign(
    Diff=df.number.diff().where(
        df.title.duplicated()
    )
)
```